# Using css selector to extract text outside of span in scrapy crawling

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, scrapy

I have the following html code:

```
    <h1>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <span>448587: </span>Brian McMills
        </a>
    </h1>
```

I'm only interested in `Brian McMills`. I would like to use scrapy `css selector` function to select the text.

When I use `h1 a ::text`, it selects only the `448587:` portion, I tried some combinations of `:not(span)` but it doesn't work.

***Note***: I'm not interested in `Xpath` or `scripting` solutions, only `css`.

Comment: Try to look here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
`h1 a:not(span)` have to works. Did you try to write in this way?

Comment: I had to add `h1 a:not(span)::text` to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked was `h1 a:not(span)::text`.

Thanks.